# Historical labels for supervised machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

So I have been told that for supervised learning or classification algorithm, the input data for training and testing includes the label (or target) as well.

So I have this very confusing thinking, where does the label comes from, people manually label the records? could be a very huge data set for training and testing, if there were a "program" or method to automatically label the records then it means that for the future data, we can have the labels as well? so why bother to predict?

Maybe I miss something... could anyone help me with a real world example? Like credit fraud and non fraud, it could be that the bank staff label the account as fraud or non fraud for which they will carry on or if they have a "formula" to indicate fraud then the "formula" should have been keep using by the bank, so where does supervisor learning come into play?

Comment: `people manually label the records?` - yes. You did not miss anything - that's exactly the right thought. Another possibility is that they conduct a very expensive experiment for few cases and then predict the others because measuring all would be too expensive.

Comment: uh huh, so the scenario to apply supervised learning would some how be like this: There has been this data set which does not have a label, the label is then manually applied for a selected subset, or maybe the whole set of data but it is too much labor work and human involved and now we want a solution that in the future the computer can do the thing for us?

Answer (score 0):

The point of supervised learning is precisely to guess what the labels would be.

So in your credit card fraud case, people have indeed been manually labelling the cases as fraudulent or not. The idea with ML is you can then guess, given what labels people have come up, what they would come up with if they saw the future data.